# How can I compute the axis of rotation of a fluid vortex from the velocity field?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

Let's say I have data on the velocity vector field of a fluid vortex such as e.g. a Hurricane available on a regular 2D grid. How can I compute the axis of rotation of the velocity vector field to determine the "center" of the Hurricane?

Comment: Are you able to visualise the data by plotting the vector field?

Comment: Hypothetically yes, but I was looking for a mathematical algorithm. Something that can be implemented on a computer. I feel like there must be a really simple answer here and I'm simply not smart enough to find it on my own.